# where and what is the error?

Tags: vb.net, elmah, asp.net-4.5

Site is running .NET 4.5, with VB. Uses SQLServer and ELMAH. I use VWD 2012.
Production site works fine, but local development site crashes with error:
"The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."
when trying to load a page in the \Admin folder, which requires login.

The error comes up in VWD on a "Source Not Available" tab as soon as the login screen shows in the browser.

The error details are:

```
*System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ReadCfwsAndThrowIfIncomplete(String data, Int32 index)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseDomain(String data, Int32& index)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data, Boolean expectMultipleAddresses, Int32& index)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddressParser.ParseAddress(String data)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
       at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage..ctor()
       at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError(Error error)
       at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.ReportError(Object state)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:*
```

ELMAH stores the error in the AllXML field as:

```
<error
  application="/VFA4"
  host="DAVE-PC"
  type="System.Web.HttpException"
  message="File does not exist."
  source="System.Web"
  detail="System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist.&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)"
  time="2014-01-13T15:15:41.7894004Z"
  statusCode="404">
  <serverVariables>
    <item
      name="ALL_HTTP">
      <value
        string="HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_ACCEPT:*/*&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-US,en;q=0.8&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_COOKIE:.ASPXANONYMOUS=YUThibsmzwEkAAAANWNhZGVjOTItNGQzNS00NmM3LTk3NjYtMTBkODAyYTBiODJhdYxJPubvb1GGRcsjrVicS0N3hCM1; VFA=ID=0&amp;Name=Visitor&amp;ACLSite=0&amp;LoggedIn=false&amp;Profile=0&amp;Greeting=Visitor&amp;Email=; FCOCRV.ASPXAUTH=2EB2E728E7546828599E7059AC071774F1B68DE36945B303364F8DE61A99F4DAEA1378B800DE77E4AD01EDCD1280072326E94CC7F9195A9AE1C8D5B829467129E14E9370F038922195F7D7FC6D7AB38936BBBC59C6C51B406783DA5C6D6567F00CB2B2AF25FD94881D778037C0EB183F8E009861; VFAanon=82GiHFGPKOy-L41M6_huRwSQi3a9FrKsTxn8DLe9u9G-5_4E45PebhWPaRXIcrD75UH17jCEDam8dBaRxfr7MOVXANsTmfdxLNxfGfGsWnq2y7yULGQg7BcCnFVfqmoMWOEp-w2; Violette=bIkdCP9-GSCYa2OhlgT3wakdXVcNXKlK1-VMT5WKlnHquMi7gMk3uIuXuEf87i7KZqH-13GVbwaqNV_7zj-pWgObGgZZPzUING_2tWJGlaLNkM4pUU6ttrVAdjyOn9bjTUBlDw2; __AntiXsrfToken=cde04d3ee0d74a9ba9af775e3dc13bb4&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_HOST:localhost:60825&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_REFERER:http://localhost:60825/VFA4/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fVFA4%2fAdmin%2fAdm-VFAMembers.aspx&#xD;&#xA;HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.72 Safari/537.36&#xD;&#xA;" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="ALL_RAW">
      <value
        string="Connection: keep-alive&#xD;&#xA;Accept: */*&#xD;&#xA;Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate&#xD;&#xA;Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8&#xD;&#xA;Cookie: .ASPXANONYMOUS=YUThibsmzwEkAAAANWNhZGVjOTItNGQzNS00NmM3LTk3NjYtMTBkODAyYTBiODJhdYxJPubvb1GGRcsjrVicS0N3hCM1; VFA=ID=0&amp;Name=Visitor&amp;ACLSite=0&amp;LoggedIn=false&amp;Profile=0&amp;Greeting=Visitor&amp;Email=; FCOCRV.ASPXAUTH=2EB2E728E7546828599E7059AC071774F1B68DE36945B303364F8DE61A99F4DAEA1378B800DE77E4AD01EDCD1280072326E94CC7F9195A9AE1C8D5B829467129E14E9370F038922195F7D7FC6D7AB38936BBBC59C6C51B406783DA5C6D6567F00CB2B2AF25FD94881D778037C0EB183F8E009861; VFAanon=82GiHFGPKOy-L41M6_huRwSQi3a9FrKsTxn8DLe9u9G-5_4E45PebhWPaRXIcrD75UH17jCEDam8dBaRxfr7MOVXANsTmfdxLNxfGfGsWnq2y7yULGQg7BcCnFVfqmoMWOEp-w2; Violette=bIkdCP9-GSCYa2OhlgT3wakdXVcNXKlK1-VMT5WKlnHquMi7gMk3uIuXuEf87i7KZqH-13GVbwaqNV_7zj-pWgObGgZZPzUING_2tWJGlaLNkM4pUU6ttrVAdjyOn9bjTUBlDw2; __AntiXsrfToken=cde04d3ee0d74a9ba9af775e3dc13bb4&#xD;&#xA;Host: localhost:60825&#xD;&#xA;Referer: http://localhost:60825/VFA4/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fVFA4%2fAdmin%2fAdm-VFAMembers.aspx&#xD;&#xA;User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.72 Safari/537.36&#xD;&#xA;" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="APPL_MD_PATH">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH">
      <value
        string="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VFA4\" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="AUTH_TYPE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="AUTH_USER">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="AUTH_PASSWORD">
      <value
        string="*****" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="LOGON_USER">
      <value
        string="DAVE-PC\Dave" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="REMOTE_USER">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_COOKIE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_FLAGS">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_ISSUER">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_KEYSIZE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_SERIALNUMBER">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_SERVER_ISSUER">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CERT_SUBJECT">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CONTENT_LENGTH">
      <value
        string="0" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="CONTENT_TYPE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="GATEWAY_INTERFACE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTPS">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTPS_KEYSIZE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="INSTANCE_ID">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="INSTANCE_META_PATH">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="LOCAL_ADDR">
      <value
        string="::1" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="PATH_INFO">
      <value
        string="/VFA4/Account/Scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="PATH_TRANSLATED">
      <value
        string="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VFA4\Account\Scripts\jquery.flexslider-min.js" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="QUERY_STRING">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="REMOTE_ADDR">
      <value
        string="::1" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="REMOTE_HOST">
      <value
        string="::1" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="REMOTE_PORT">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="REQUEST_METHOD">
      <value
        string="GET" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="SCRIPT_NAME">
      <value
        string="/VFA4/Account/Scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="SERVER_NAME">
      <value
        string="localhost" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="SERVER_PORT">
      <value
        string="60825" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="SERVER_PORT_SECURE">
      <value
        string="0" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="SERVER_PROTOCOL">
      <value
        string="HTTP/1.1" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="SERVER_SOFTWARE">
      <value
        string="" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="URL">
      <value
        string="/VFA4/Account/Scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_CONNECTION">
      <value
        string="keep-alive" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_ACCEPT">
      <value
        string="*/*" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING">
      <value
        string="gzip, deflate" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE">
      <value
        string="en-US,en;q=0.8" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_COOKIE">
      <value
        string=".ASPXANONYMOUS=YUThibsmzwEkAAAANWNhZGVjOTItNGQzNS00NmM3LTk3NjYtMTBkODAyYTBiODJhdYxJPubvb1GGRcsjrVicS0N3hCM1; VFA=ID=0&amp;Name=Visitor&amp;ACLSite=0&amp;LoggedIn=false&amp;Profile=0&amp;Greeting=Visitor&amp;Email=; FCOCRV.ASPXAUTH=2EB2E728E7546828599E7059AC071774F1B68DE36945B303364F8DE61A99F4DAEA1378B800DE77E4AD01EDCD1280072326E94CC7F9195A9AE1C8D5B829467129E14E9370F038922195F7D7FC6D7AB38936BBBC59C6C51B406783DA5C6D6567F00CB2B2AF25FD94881D778037C0EB183F8E009861; VFAanon=82GiHFGPKOy-L41M6_huRwSQi3a9FrKsTxn8DLe9u9G-5_4E45PebhWPaRXIcrD75UH17jCEDam8dBaRxfr7MOVXANsTmfdxLNxfGfGsWnq2y7yULGQg7BcCnFVfqmoMWOEp-w2; Violette=bIkdCP9-GSCYa2OhlgT3wakdXVcNXKlK1-VMT5WKlnHquMi7gMk3uIuXuEf87i7KZqH-13GVbwaqNV_7zj-pWgObGgZZPzUING_2tWJGlaLNkM4pUU6ttrVAdjyOn9bjTUBlDw2; __AntiXsrfToken=cde04d3ee0d74a9ba9af775e3dc13bb4" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_HOST">
      <value
        string="localhost:60825" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_REFERER">
      <value
        string="http://localhost:60825/VFA4/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fVFA4%2fAdmin%2fAdm-VFAMembers.aspx" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="HTTP_USER_AGENT">
      <value
        string="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.72 Safari/537.36" />
    </item>
  </serverVariables>
  <cookies>
    <item
      name=".ASPXANONYMOUS">
      <value
        string="YUThibsmzwEkAAAANWNhZGVjOTItNGQzNS00NmM3LTk3NjYtMTBkODAyYTBiODJhdYxJPubvb1GGRcsjrVicS0N3hCM1" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="VFA">
      <value
        string="ID=0&amp;Name=Visitor&amp;ACLSite=0&amp;LoggedIn=false&amp;Profile=0&amp;Greeting=Visitor&amp;Email=" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="FCOCRV.ASPXAUTH">
      <value
        string="2EB2E728E7546828599E7059AC071774F1B68DE36945B303364F8DE61A99F4DAEA1378B800DE77E4AD01EDCD1280072326E94CC7F9195A9AE1C8D5B829467129E14E9370F038922195F7D7FC6D7AB38936BBBC59C6C51B406783DA5C6D6567F00CB2B2AF25FD94881D778037C0EB183F8E009861" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="VFAanon">
      <value
        string="82GiHFGPKOy-L41M6_huRwSQi3a9FrKsTxn8DLe9u9G-5_4E45PebhWPaRXIcrD75UH17jCEDam8dBaRxfr7MOVXANsTmfdxLNxfGfGsWnq2y7yULGQg7BcCnFVfqmoMWOEp-w2" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="Violette">
      <value
        string="bIkdCP9-GSCYa2OhlgT3wakdXVcNXKlK1-VMT5WKlnHquMi7gMk3uIuXuEf87i7KZqH-13GVbwaqNV_7zj-pWgObGgZZPzUING_2tWJGlaLNkM4pUU6ttrVAdjyOn9bjTUBlDw2" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="__AntiXsrfToken">
      <value
        string="cde04d3ee0d74a9ba9af775e3dc13bb4" />
    </item>
  </cookies>
</error>
```

I cannot determine if the error is in the ELMAH process or in the underlying code somewhere. I have checked the email info in web.config related to ELMAH and all email addresses are properly formatted.

Everything had been working fine on the development machine until sometime in December, when all of a sudden this came up.

Comment: Maybe you always had this email error (check all your emails to make sure they are valid). But it was the first time you had the error in your thread. You can't see the thread error because it crashes when trying to send you the error.

Comment: Looking back in the ELMAH logs I think I got ELMAH started on 12/17/2013 and the error showed up immediately when running locally but not on production. And yes, I think the ELMAH error comes up when trying to notify me of the triggering error.